# Tests of Forecast Accuracy for Nested Models

Tags: forecasting, accuracy, model-comparison, nested-models, diebold-mariano-test

Can anyone explain why "classic" tests of forecast accuracy, (i.e. Diebold-Mariano test, Meese-Rogoff test and Morgan-Granger-Newbold test) are not suited for nested models?

I could not find a good explanation in literature.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139462/diebold-mariano-test-for-predictive-accuracy

Answer (score 5):

The Diebold-Mariano test is well suited for the purpose it was designed for: to assess whether two forecasts produce loss of equal size in population. This holds regardless of the models that were used to generate these forecasts. (Actually, models are not needed; survey forecasts or market-based forecasts can be assessed as well.)

[Diebold (2015)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) remarks:

> The DM test was intended for comparing forecasts; it has been, and remains, useful in that regard. <...> For comparing forecasts, DM is the only game in town. There’s really nothing more to say.

The problems begin when the test is used to compare models rather than forecasts.

> The DM test was not intended for comparing models. Unfortunately, however, much of the subsequent literature uses DM-type tests for comparing models, in pseudo-out-of-sample environments. In that case, simpler yet more compelling full-sample model comparison procedures exist; they have been, and should continue to be, widely used.

The problem with comparing models is that the main assumption *that the loss differential be covariance stationary* gets violated, resulting in null distributions of the test statistic that are not the same as the one of comparing forecasts. When this is ignored, things get sour.

> For comparing models, with estimated parameters, the situation is more nuanced. DM-style tests are still indisputably relevant, but the issue arises as to appropriate critical values.

([Diebold (2015)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) gives a detailed explanation of what goes on there, but I will skip it since you seem to be interested in forecasts rather than models.)

But **why** is a comparison of (model-based) forecasts different from a comparison of models? Because there are two different questions being asked:

1. Which forecast is better (not only in this particular sample, but in population)? vs.
2. Which model is more likely to have generated the data?

You could have Model A that generated the data but that is difficult to estimate with high precision. Once estimated, Model A produces poor forecasts due to the estimation imprecision.
You could have Model B that did not generate the data but approximates the data quite well and is also easy to estimate with high precision. Once estimated, Model B delivers rather accurate forecasts (more accurate than those from Model A).
Forecasts generated by Model B is the answer to question 1, while Model A is the answer to question 2.

**Edit:** [Elliott and Timmermann (2016)](https://cloudfront.escholarship.org/dist/prd/content/qt6z55v472/qt6z55v472.pdf) include a brief explanation of the case of nested models on p. 103-104 where the nested model may deliver inferior forecasts in practice but would deliver superior forecasts under perfect estimation precision (no error in estimating model parameters), which is a hypothetical setting.

**References:**

- Diebold, Francis X. ["Comparing predictive accuracy, twenty years later: A personal perspective on the use and abuse of Diebold–Mariano tests."](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.2014.983236) *Journal of Business & Economic Statistics* 33.1 (2015): 1-1.
  (Ungated version [here](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper113/Diebold_DM%20Test.pdf).)
- Elliott, G., & Timmermann, A. (2016). [Forecasting in economics and finance](https://cloudfront.escholarship.org/dist/prd/content/qt6z55v472/qt6z55v472.pdf). *Annual Review of Economics, 8*, 81-110.

Comment: Wow, what a neat explanation. Took me couple of years of forecasting to realise that better forecast accuracy does not say much about the correctness of the model.